# How to override a library defined type with a custom definition?

Tags: typescript

I am building an application in Typescript 3.8. A library I would like to use has an exported type that uses a template literal string, which is only supported in Typescript 4.1+ and causing my build to fail.

I would like to replace the library's type with my own that creates a union of all possible values, achieving the same result in a way that is compatible with my version of typescript.

```
// Library's exported type
export declare type AlignedPlacement = `${Side}-${Alignment}`;

// My new type
type AlignedPlacement = 'top-start' | 'top-end' | 'right-start' | 'right-end' | 'bottom-start' | 'bottom-end' | 'left-start' | 'left-end';
```

I have tried to do this with Module Augmentation, like so, but I get a Duplicate Identifier error - it only seems to work for overriding interfaces, not types.

```
declare module '@floating-ui/core' {
    type AlignedPlacement =
        | 'top-start'
        | 'top-end'
        | 'right-start'
        | 'right-end'
        | 'bottom-start'
        | 'bottom-end'
        | 'left-start'
        | 'left-end';
}
```

I have found an example of this problem being fixed using `patch-package` (https://github.com/floating-ui/floating-ui/issues/1584#issuecomment-1071501851), but I really don't want to introduce another dependency to my application just to fix this issue. It feels like something that should be possible within Typescript.

Any help would be appreciated - thank you!

Comment: It isn't possible. Might as well just use your own type instead of replacing theirs...

Comment: Have you tried the way mentioned on https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-override-interface-property page?

Comment: @caTS I'm not actually trying to use the type, I'm just trying to override theirs because it requires a newer version of Typescript and breaks my build

Comment: @RaviNain that method is for interfaces, I'm trying to override a plain type

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using the `patch-package` solution described by the link in my question

https://github.com/floating-ui/floating-ui/issues/1584#issuecomment-1071501851